# Index formula to copy entire row with a date range

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-2013

Excel 2013 - 
Sheet 1 is titled "Results" and some of the data includes a date (Column L), an agent's name (Column M), and customer comments (Column N). Sheet 3 is titled "Report".

On sheet 3 I need a formula that looks at the date range column and automatically copies the entire row of data if it falls within a specific date range (I can either manually type in the range like from 9/24/18 - 9/30/18, or if possible I would like it to automatically only copy data from the previous week).

Essentially, if an agent had a positive comment left for them in the previous week I want the date, agent's name, and the comment itself to copy automatically to the "Report" sheet.

Comment: What have you tried please and where did you get stuck with your formula/coding? If unsure on how to post please see the help resources [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you paste this in a 3 column array, it should pop out what you want

```
= INDIRECT("Results!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INT(NOW()/7-1)*7+1,Results!L:L,1),12) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INT(NOW()/7-1)*7+8,Results!L:L,1)-1,14))
```

By taking the int value of NOW()/7 we essentially figure out how many weeks it's been from the January 1, 1900; by subtracting one from INT(NOW/7), we get what the week prior was. Multiplying by 7 again is to get it into a value that the date format can display properly and adding one pushes the day from Saturday to Sunday.

Match allows us to look for the date that we just found and tells us how far down it is in the range L:L which is the row number it's on. We can then use this information to get an Address based off the row and column position by using the ADDRESS function.

The second Match searches for the start of the current week, but we return up to the cell just before it to ensure that we get all of the cells for the Saturday the week prior. This is of course assuming all the cells are sorted in order of date.

Lastly, it's important to use indirect in this case because it allows us to use the values we just found and concatenate them with the sheet name so Excel can see it as a valid reference to cells and not just some mumbo jumbo.